# Garbage Collector: Taking care of object with a reference to singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, garbage-collection, singleton

Imagine such situation: you have a singleton object and a class that has a field that points to this singleton

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly MySingleton singleton = MySingleton.Instance;
    ...
}
```

And now you have an WebApi Controller and in every request you are creating new object of type MyClass.

My question is: what will happen with such an object? Will it be removed by garbage collector when the request will end? Or will it be hanging in memory until the singleton will be collected?

Forgive me if this is stupid question, but I'm curious.

Comment: Singleton per definition will never be garbage collected, cause you have a static reference to the instance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be collected if there are no dependencies which really will pin your object. There you just have a reference to the Singleton object.

If Singleton somehow retains a refence to your Controllers, than yes, your contollers will be hold in memory.

Comment: I'm asking if the object of MyClass created in controller action will be hold in memory because of a reference to singleton

Comment: If you subscribe to events on a static (or singleton) class, then that class will also hold a reference to the subscriber. Though that's very unlikely to happen in ASP.NET